# How to solve UI having different sizes? Mediaquery doesn't solve text UI

Tags: flutter, user-interface, media-queries

Been using mediaquery all along to size for different screens.

Let's take for an example, a card with text within.
Started testing on different phone sizes only to realize that the card changes size but the text doesn't. So it looks weird on bigger phones - lots of empty spaces.

is there a way to make text size responsive?

Failing that I would see that making card size an absolute size on all phones as a possible solution? But that would also result in more weird empty spaces all around.

Does anyone have a better solution? Relative size, responsive to phone size is definitely the best! Thanks!

Comment: Check auto_size_text package. It basically does what you need in a combo with a fractionally sized widget :)

Comment: will do so, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `MediaQuery` for the `fontSize` in the TextStyle like below:

```
Text(
  'Ladies and gentlemen, you could have been anywhere in the world tonight, but you’re here with us in New York City.',
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1),
)
```